# Extra \N{...} when using kCFStringTransformToUnicodeName or NSStringTransformToUnicodeName

Tags: swift, nsstring, foundation, core-foundation, cfstring

```
let string = "\u{00A0}" // no-break space
let transformed = string.stringByApplyingTransform(NSStringTransformToUnicodeName, reverse: false)
```

Expected result: `NO-BREAK SPACE`

Actual result: `\N{NO_BREAK_SPACE}`

Why the extra `\N{` and `}`? What are they for, and is there any way to remove them, short of regex/scanning/parsing/etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the way ICU & Unicode represent named code points in Regular Expressions. So I'm not surprised by that output at all.

[Here is a link that reference this syntax at unicode.org](http://unicode.org/reports/tr18/#Individually_Named_Characters).

That's also explained [in this other page at ICU Project](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp#TOC-Regular-Expression-Metacharacters).

*PS: `\N{}` is actually the shorter equivalent to `\p{name=…}` — as explained in that unicode.org page above that linked anchor). You can see similar syntaxes like in [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) that mention that `\p{…}` syntax for defining Unicode CodePoints using their properties.*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was going to strip those characters out, but now that I know that they’re official unicode code point names, I’ll leave them in. (This is for printing out a readable debug version of a string that may contain special characters that are hard to read in a monospace font.)